# TWiki install/config problems

Tags: installation, twiki

Debian Etch/Apache 1.3

I have one server happily running TWiki, and want to replicate it on a 2nd server. Apt-get install twiki runs OK except for an apache2 failure. It does appear to have worked out it need to use apache 1.3 though I could be persuaded otherwise!

However, when I got to

myhost/twiki

it successfully goes to /twiki/bin/view.pl/XXX/WebHome but returns

The requested URL /twiki/bin/view.pl/XXX/WebHome was not found on this server.

Apache log shows

File does not exist: /var/www/packages/twiki/bin/view.pl/XXX/WebHome

On the working system, there is no .pl extension on the 'view' which may be vital. Also, I can't see why the packages get installed to the packages dir, but I have moved twiki dir under this. Not sure if the apache config needs to be changed.

It would make life simpler if I could remove the 'packages' dir from things but can't see how.

Any help on this appreciated!

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

mmm, I stopped maintaining the twiki packages when we forked the project to foswiki.

however. I don't recal ever putting the twiki files into /var/www/packages.

where are you getting the twiki packages from ?

http://fosiki.com/blog/2007/04/22/debian-repository-for-twiki/ are probably more up to date (than the deb in debian's own repository) - and includes plugins, but i've not used / tested anything since 2008 - but that repo does include all the plugins from twiki.org.

i think your dependancy on apache 1.3 issue is because this is a quite old debian package -

http://distributedinformation.com/experimental/dists/experimental/main/binary-i386/Packages depends on apache2

if you're rolling your own, there's an apache cfg generator topic on twiki.org somewhere - we've made many updates to our version on foswiki.org

Sven

Comment: Thanks Sven - the '/var/www/packages' issue is a server issue I think, not a Twiki issue. I'm not sure where it's set though.